# Is there a time limit for the startup script to finish before it stops?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to create a VM instance in google compute engine with a startup script that takes 30 minutes, but it never finishes, it stops around 10 minutes after the instance boots. Is there a timeout? Is there another alternative to accomplish what I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what does your startup script do that takes 30min? Download / install / configure software? Can you do it after VM boots, using tools like Chef, Ansible, Puppet, Salt, etc.? They will also help you update / reconfigure live VMs while they're running, rather than only at startup time. Alternatively, you can prebuild custom VM images using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/).

Comment: @MishaBrukman My script downloads another script and then executes it, and what that script does is download some big files, and then compute some values based on latitude/longitude. Then, when the process is finished, the VM is destroyed. I had this process working without problems in digital ocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additional clarification in the comments:

> My script downloads another script and then executes it, and what that script does is download some big files, and then compute some values based on latitude/longitude. Then, when the process is finished, the VM is destroyed.

My recommendation would be to run the large download and processing asynchronously rather than synchronously. The reason being is that if it's synchronous, it's part of the VM startup (in the critical path), and the VM monitoring infrastructure notices that the VM is not completing its startup phase within a reasonable amount of time and is terminating it.

Instead, take the heavy-duty processing out of the critical path and do it in the background, i.e., asynchronously.

In other words, the startup script currently probably looks like:

```sh
# Download the external script
curl [...] -o /tmp/script.sh

# Run the file download, computation, etc. and shut down the VM.
/tmp/script.sh
```

I would suggest converting this to:

```sh
# Download the external script
curl [...] -o /tmp/script.sh

# Run the file download, computation, etc. and shut down the VM.
nohup /tmp/script.sh &
```

What this does is start the heavy processing in the background, but also disconnect it from the parent process such that it is not automatically terminated when the parent process (the actual startup script) is terminated. We want the main startup script to terminate so that the entire VM startup phase is marked completed.

For more info, see the [Wikipedia page on `nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this solution and let you know

Comment: While this pattern works, I suspect it is causing issues for me and my team. Instead, a process monitor (systemd or supervisord) is likely a better solution.